# Module to query Active Directory after March 2020 update for LDAP channel binding and LDAP signing

Tags: active-directory, ldap, puppet

There will be a Microsoft Active Directory update in March 2020 that enables LDAP channel binding and LDAP signing as default, see https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/4520412/2020-ldap-channel-binding-and-ldap-signing-requirement-for-windows

Are there any modules in puppet where I can query Active Directory for data used in manifests that will work, when LDAP channel binding and LDAP signing is activated?

I now use gerardkok-hiera5_ldap which uses (j)ruby-ldap gem. Both are a few years old and I could not find any information, if they will work after the Microsoft change.

So will this still work or are there any other modules that I can use to query the Active Directory afterwards?

Thanks in advance.